# ssis variable syntax conflicts with mysql output variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ssis

I've created an SSIS package that needs to execute a MySQL SPROC with an output parameter.

The MySQL SPROC works fine from Query Browser.

The problem is that the @ character is used to mark a SSIS variable and also is used as a MySQL sproc variable for output.  The step does not work in SSIS.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Have you tried using \x0040 ? That's the Unicode sequence for '@', and the expression editor is built to allow those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution:

I created a step that generates the variable query.

I execute the variable query as variable input instead of direct input.